# Problema con Contador en JSTL o cambiar por un for(int i)

Tags: java, jsp

Necesito llevar una variable contador en un html usando JSTL porque el JSTL usa un Foreach en vez de un for(int i..)

He probado con : Da error

```
  <c:set var="i" value="-1"/>
     <c:forEach items="${finalmente}" var="dato"> 
         <c:set var="i" value="${i=i+1}"/>
          <c:out value="${i}"/>
      </c:forEach>
```

Pinta literalmente "i++"

```
      <c:set var="i" value="-1"/>
         <c:forEach items="${finalmente}" var="dato"> 
             <c:set var="i" value="i++"/>
              <c:out value="${i}"/>
          </c:forEach>
```

No hace nada:

```
                 <fmt:parseNumber var = "id" type = "number" value = "-1" />
                        <c:forEach items="${finalmente}" var="dato"> 
                              <fmt:parseNumber var = "id" type = "number" value = ${id+1} />
                                    <c:out value="${id}"/>
                         </c:forEach>
```

Necesito alguna forma de llevar un contador.
También me vale la opción de recorrer en Spring MVC el Array "finalmente" sin tener que usar , pero no sé como hacerlo con Spring

Los Array los mando a la vista con :

```
vista.addObject("finalmente", ArrayOrdenado);
```

Cualquiera de las 2 opciones me vale:
Llevar un contador con JSTL o recorrer el "finalmente" con un for(int i) en el html.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera correcta es así:

```
<c:set var="i" value="1"/>
<c:forEach items="${finalmente}" var="dato">
  <c:out value="${i}"/>
  <c:set var="i" value="${i+1}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Ya que en JSTL no se puede hacer con el post incremento, lo que debe hacer es volver a setearle el dato (valor) a la variable.